# Join two tables and return data from both

Tags: stored-procedures, join, crystal-reports

I have three tables as.

```
**Table 1**                 **Table 2**                   **Table 3**
 Lot_no(pk)                  Lot_no(pk/fk)                    Lot_no(fk)
 Name                        job type                        Material
 Phone                      Printing qty                     Trim
```

look at sample data

---

```
 **Table 1**             **Table 2**                      **Table 3**

  1 Mian Sultan xyz        1 Reverse 50,000pcs               1 PVC 20
  2 Mian Usman xyz         2 New 10,000pcs                   1 INK 30  
                                                             2 MILKY 25 
                                                             2 INK 35
```

---

I just want to show data from table 2 & table 3 on the basis of lot_no.
for example user enter lot_no=1 then result should be displayed as

```
1    Reverse  50,000pcs  
1    PVC  20
1    INK  30
```

if user enter lot_no=2 then similarly

```
2    New      10,000pcs
2    MILKY     25
2    INK       35
```

my query is as follows....
@lotnum int (Variable declaration in stored procedure)

```
SELECT table2.lot_no, table2.job_type, table2.printing qty,
table3.material, table3.trim
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 ON (table2.lot_no=table3.lot_no)
WHERE table2.lot_no=@lotnum AND table3.lot_no=@lotnum;
```

it shows me the Correct result but when i use this in Crystal Report it Shows only..... when lot_no=1

```
1    Reverse  50,000pcs  
1    PVC  20
```

it don't show

```
1    INK  30
```

Similar case when lot_no=2.
Please Guide me thanks.

Comment: have you used the query as it is in crystal reprots? or did you made any changes?

Comment: I have used this query in sql server but not yet in Crystal reports. If my query is wrong please guide me

Comment: Use same query as it is in crystal reports...in command of the database expert

Comment: when i'm using a stored procedure or add two tables table2 & 3 in database expert it gives me coreect result from table2 but pick first row from table3 with same lot no say when lot no =1 it shows 1   PVC   20 but when i press a next navigation button for next record then it will show me second record of table3 as 1  INK   30 . I want to show both lot no records 1 PVC 20 & 1  INK  30 from table3 at the same page.